# When trying to verify a cert to link to Betfair API I am receiving an Exception (shown in text body) I can't understand why it would be showing this?

Tags: python, exception, betfair

My code and the exception are as follows -

```
# Import libraries

 import betfairlightweight
 from betfairlightweight import APIClient
 import os

# Print the current working directory

 print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

# Print the contents of the directory

 print("Contents of the directory:")
 for item in os.listdir("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xcacerts\\"):
 print(item)

# Certificate path for betfair

 certs_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xcacerts\\"

# Betfair login and app key

 my_username = "xxxxx"
 my_password = "xxxxx"
 my_app_key = "xxxxxx"

    try:
    \# Initialize the Betfair API client
    trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username=my_username,
    password=my_password,
    app_key=my_app_key,
    certs=certs_path)

    # Attempt to login
    trading.login()

# Check if login was successful
if trading.session_token:
    print("Login successful.")
else:
    print("Login failed. Check your credentials.")

except Exception as e:
print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

The error is -

> An error occurred: None
> Params: None
> Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='identitysso-cert.betfair.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/certlogin (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(524297, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3900)')))

I have tried the following -

Update SSL Library: Ensure that your SSL library is up to date. You can update your SSL library through your package manager or by upgrading Python itself.

Verify SSL Certificate: Check if the SSL certificate used by the server (identitysso-cert.betfair.com in this case) is valid and trusted. You can do this by opening the URL in a web browser and inspecting the certificate details.

Answer (score 0):

I haver never used Betfair lightweight or Python so this is just a suggestion. It may be you are missing an 'ssoid' as part of your authentication?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).